# Why does my ASP.NET Core MVC app run in the wrong wwwroot path?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

My `DocumenRoot` folder is on `/var/www/html` (CentOS 7.4)

I install my ASP.NET Core MVC app in a subfolder `/var/www/html/mya/app/v1`

I expect to access it from the internet using

`https://apps.example.com/mya/app/v1`

I have copied all of required css, js, images files into `/var/www/html/mya/app/v1/webroot`

Why does it look like it keeps going on the wrong path?

=== Startup.cs ===

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
     endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
     name: "default",
     pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

== Program.cs ===

```
 .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
 {
      webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>()

      #if !DEBUG
 .UseContentRoot(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location))
      #endif

      .UseUrls("http://127.0.0.1:500");
   });
```

=== Console ===

```
GET https://apps.example.com/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
GET https://apps.example.com/lib/@coreui/coreui/dist/css/coreui.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
GET https://apps.example.com/lib/@coreui/icons/css/free.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
GET https://apps.example.com/lib/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
GET https://apps.example.com/lib/bootstrap-table/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
GET https://apps.example.com/lib/@popperjs/core/dist/umd/popper.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
GET https://apps.example.com/image/logo-small.png 404 (Not Found)
GET https://apps.example.com/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
GET https://apps.example.com/lib/@coreui/coreui/dist/js/coreui.bundle.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
GET https://apps.example.com/lib/bootstrap-table/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
GET https://apps.example.com/js/site.js?v=PyStcLVmxSbO176wn2m8D95rLCh75CNK1zHD1dW8f-A net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: This *most likely* is really ASP.NET **Core** MVC - right?? If so : update the text (title + body) and use the `asp.net-core-mvc` tag to make this clear

Comment: thank you, could you please more detail as I am new to ASP.NET Core MVC (still learning process)

Comment: It looks that you just copy the Asp.net Core MVC application to the `v1` folder, then you want to access the web site via the internet, right? Please check the article: [Host ASP.NET Core on Linux with Apache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-apache?view=aspnetcore-5.0), after creating an Asp.net core Web application, we should publish and copy over the app to the hosted server. Since you are using CentOS, you should also configure a reverse proxy server (such as: Apache and Nginx), then user can access the web app via the internet.